# What happens if I attempt to romance either character?

Tags: saints-row-iv

In Saints Row IV, there comes a point where The Protagonist is able to exit and enter the Simulation freely through Gateways. If the player exits the Simulation through one of said Gateways, they are transported to a Zin ship on which the Protagonist, Kinzie, and Keith have set up a sort of base. Here, the player may interact with the two NPCs. Specifically, they can choose to either talk to or "Romance" the character.

It sounds like it should be obvious what the second option does, but I'm still quite curious. What exactly will happen if you choose to romance one of the NPCs? Additionally, does the outcome depend on your character's gender and which NPC (Kinzie or Keith) that the Protagonist attempts to romance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "Romance" option isn't a long term thing the way it is in the Mass Effect series. It's just a short, amusing cutscene that can be done with as many characters as you want, as often as you want. Each character has their own "Romance" cutscene.

Answer (score 5):

It will just play an often hilarious cutscene for each character. It is the same no matter which gender you are. It does not affect the story and doesn't have any other outcomes. It's just for fun, and to make fun of awkward love scenes in other games.